# How to set Value which is get from Common class(retrofit)

Tags: android, retrofit

I have `fragment` and Common class which inside it used `retrofit` callback..I have Connect_and_get class.It sends request to server and gets information.I must use this information in my `fragment`.. But I can't return result onResponse.How can I do it..(Response is coming well from server)

Please see my code

```
public class Connect_and_Get {
           private int size;
         private OkHttpClient.Builder httpClient;
        private ApiService client;
        private Call<Response> call;
        private MyPreference myPreference;
        String a[] = {"secret"};
        String b[] = {"secret"};


        public int Connect_and_Get() {
            Requests request;
            request = new Requests("tasks.list", new params(20, 0, a, b, "", "", "", "", ""));
            httpClient = new OkHttpClient.Builder();

            httpClient.addInterceptor(new Interceptor() {
                @Override
                public okhttp3.Response intercept(Chain chain) throws IOException {
                    Request request = chain.request().newBuilder().addHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " + "secret").build();
                    return chain.proceed(request);
                }
            });

            Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                    .baseUrl(Constants.baseUrl)
                    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                    .client(httpClient.build())
                    .build();
            client = retrofit.create(ApiService.class);
            call = client.getDocument(request);
            call.enqueue(new Callback<Response>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(Call<Response> call, retrofit2.Response<Response> response) {
                    size = response.body().getResult().getList().size();

                }

                @Override
                public void onFailure(Call<Response> call, Throwable t) {

                }
            });

            //retruning information
            return size;
        }
    }
```

and result from common class coming 0;Because it doesn't wait my response so it is returning 0;

In fragment

```
      Connect_and_Get a = new Connect_and_Get();
    int getting = a.Connect_and_Get();
    Log.d("mylog", "result:"+String.valueOf(getting));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declare an interface like this

```
   public interface ResponseListener {

     public int onResponse(int size);
```

}

and use below code in your activity

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements ResponseListener {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    new Connect_and_Get().Connect_and_Get(this);

}


@Override
public int onResponse(int size) {
    // to do
    return 0;
}
```

}

modify your connect class like this

```
 public class Connect_and_Get {


    public int Connect_and_Get(ResponseListener responseListener) {
       // as it was

        call.enqueue(new Callback<Response>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<Response> call, retrofit2.Response<Response> response) {
                size = response.body().getResult().getList().size();
                responseListener.onResponse(size);
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<Response> call, Throwable t) {

            }
        });


    }
}
```

Comment: You are doing public int Connect_and_Get(ResponseListener responseListener) but setting   new Connect_and_Get().Connect_and_Get(this);

Comment: I have fixed it..Thank you very much

Comment: I want to send data from mother fragment to child fragment and in every click data must be sent to child fragment and use method in child fragment should work according to incoming data every time

Comment: create a bundle and send data to child fragment  (childFragment.setArguments(bundle)). use method getArguments() on child fragment . Now you have data in bundle. rest is complete childfragment.

Comment: But this method I think works one time only.. I should send data to child fragment in every click..So in every click child fragment should use method like  public void Search(String string){new request to server according to string}...Pls bro help me

Comment: if your child fragment has height match_parent then this way will work.get your desired data (searchKey) on childFragment from bundle and call search(searchKey) in oncreate of child fragment

Answer (score 0):

You need to check whether your response is successful or not.
Check the code below.

```
call.enqueue(new Callback<Response>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<Response> call, retrofit2.Response<Response> response) {
            if(response.isSuccessful()){
              //enter code here
            } else {
              //Error Message
            }


        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<Response> call, Throwable t) {
             Log.e("Log", "Error -> "+t.getLocalizedMessage());
        }
    });
```

Comment: response is successful..Result is coming..But problem is I cant return result to my fragement.On Response return size isnot allowed

Comment: You can create an interface with a method getResultCount(int count) and create is setter method in fragment. Set it from your activity while creating your fragment object. And Implement the interface on your activity, getResultCount(int count) will become your activity's override method. Then you can fire it like *yourInterfaceObject.getResultCount(yourValue)* in your onResponse method.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an event bus like (rxbus,otto, etc..) to post events across your app when the response from the api ready to use .

Retrofit callback sample code:

```
call.enqueue(new Callback<Response>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<Response> call, retrofit2.Response<Response> response) {
           Bus.getInstance.post(Event)

        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<Response> call, Throwable t) {

        }
    });
```

Fragment sample:

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        Bus.getInstance.register(this)
    }



@Subscribe
    public void onCallDone(Event response) {
        //enter code here
    }
```

Comment: is it library? how can i use it(Implementing)

Comment: where i use onCallDone?I used outside onCreate so it is in black(never used)

Comment: the code will run when an event is post and the fragment is subscribed to event bus .